# Does Flutter Web's "compute()" work on it's own thread or web worker, or how does it work?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

If I do this, for example:

```
FutureBuilder(
   initialData: null,
   future: compute(expensiveParsingOperation, data),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(!snapshot.hasData){
          // This doesn't spin (frozen).  The entire UI is janked until the expensive operation future completes.
          CircularProgressIndicator(); 
        }else {  
             Container(); 
         } 
});
```

I expected the above to send `expensiveParsingOperation` function to a web worker or something and not jank the main thread, but this is not what is occurring in my observation.

Comment: I found a small Dart library that will help you to use Web Workers in Dart as Isolate integration on web has been discontinued with Dart 2.

Check out https://github.com/deakjahn/flutter_isolate_web

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`compute` does nothing on the web platform at this time
see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33577